# How to display the plot with total numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can anyone tell me how to show the top of value

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=mpg,fill=cyl))+
geom_bar(stat='identity',position=position_dodge(width=0.5),width=0.3)+
  geom_text(aes(x = month, y = revenue, label = revenue, group = type ),position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),vjust = 1)+
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "top",
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10, angle = 0, hjust = 1))+
  labs(x="", y="Rupees (In Lakhs)", fill="")+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details about what you want to see. I don't know what you mean by "show the top of value".

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking this up! Check out the vjust argument in geom_text(), which lets you adjust the vertical justification of the text geoms.

Comment: but i want to display only top of the value